# What does it mean when your psql prompt looks like my_database=?>

Tags: postgresql, psql

I fat-fingered something and then my psql prompt looked like this (note the unusual question mark):

```
my_database=?>
```

I thought that looked unusual so I quit and restarted psql and then the question mark was gone. I was curious about why the question mark appeared but Googling has failed me. Have you ever seen this before?

Comment: You can [customize the prompt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING). By default an indeterminate transaction status will show up as a `?`.

Comment: (I had no knowledge of this before seeing your question but an obvious thing for a database tool to want to alert you to is transaction status and a quick google confirmed)

Comment: I think I may have found my answer, it's a pretty obscure detail on this page, but it says "Transaction status [is] ? when the transaction state is indeterminate (for example, because there is no connection)." So maybe I had a connection issue during my psql session. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever your googling skills surpass my own, took me a while to find that. :)